# Having Issue With Enemy AI - Java

Tags: java, swing, artificial-intelligence

I am having an issue with enemy AI. The AI I am using right now is a dog.

What the dog is supposed to do -

The dog is supposed to follow the player if the player is within 200px of the dog. It's supposed to stay 100 pixels away from the character at all times. The dog will later shoot projectiles, which I can do easily

My main issue is that the dog seems to just be attacking the player from it's origin, (0,0), or the top left of the player image.

I tried adding 8 points around the player that the dog will constantly check on a loop which one he is closest to. He will move towards whichever one he is closest to, thus following the player but at a distance.

This is how I tried accomplishing this:

```
int p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y,p3x,p3y,p4x,p4y,p5x,p5y,p6x,p6y,p7x,p7y,p8x,p8y,p1final,p2final,p3final,p4final,p5final,p6final,p7final,p8final;
    p1x = Game.px - 350;
    p1y = Game.py - 350;
    p2x = Game.px;
    p2y = Game.py - 350;
    p3x = Game.px + 350;
    p3y = Game.py - 350;
    p4x = Game.px + 350;
    p4y = Game.py;
    p5x = Game.px + 350;
    p5y = Game.py + 350;
    p6x = Game.px;
    p6y = Game.py + 350;
    p7x = Game.px - 350;
    p7y = Game.py + 350;
    p8x = Game.px - 350;
    p8y = Game.py;
    p1final = 0;
    p2final = 0;
    p3final = 0;
    p4final = 0;
    p5final = 0;
    p6final = 0;
    p7final = 0;
    p8final = 0;
        if(x >= p1x){
            p1final = p1final + (x - p1x);
        }
        if(y < p1y){
            p1final = p1final + (p1y - y);
        }
        if(x < p1x){
            p1final = p1final + (p1x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p1y){
            p1final = p1final + (y - p1y);
        }
        if(x >= p2x){
            p2final = p2final + (x - p2x);
        }
        if(y < p2y){
            p2final = p2final + (p2y - y);
        }
        if(x < p2x){
            p2final = p2final + (p2x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p2y){
            p2final = p2final + (y - p2y);
        }
        if(x >= p3x){
            p3final = p3final + (x - p3x);
        }
        if(y < p3y){
            p3final = p3final + (p3y - y);
        }
        if(x < p3x){
            p3final = p3final + (p3x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p3y){
            p3final = p3final + (y - p3y);
        }
        if(x >= p4x){
            p4final = p4final + (x - p4x);
        }
        if(y < p4y){
            p4final = p4final + (p4y - y);
        }
        if(x < p4x){
            p4final = p4final + (p4x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p4y){
            p4final = p4final + (y - p4y);
        }
        if(x >= p5x){
            p5final = p5final + (x - p5x);
        }
        if(y < p5y){
            p5final = p5final + (p5y - y);
        }
        if(x < p5x){
            p5final = p5final + (p5x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p5y){
            p5final = p5final + (y - p5y);
        }
        if(x >= p6x){
            p6final = p6final + (x - p6x);
        }
        if(y < p6y){
            p6final = p6final + (p6y - y);
        }
        if(x < p6x){
            p6final = p6final + (p6x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p6y){
            p6final = p6final + (y - p6y);
        }
        if(x >= p7x){
            p7final = p7final + (x - p7x);
        }
        if(y < p7y){
            p7final = p7final + (p7y - y);
        }
        if(x < p7x){
            p7final = p7final + (p7x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p7y){
            p7final = p7final + (y - p7y);
        }
        if(x >= p8x){
            p8final = p8final + (x - p8x);
        }
        if(y < p8y){
            p8final = p8final + (p8y - y);
        }
        if(x < p8x){
            p8final = p8final + (p8x - x);
        }
        if(y >= p8y){
            p8final = p8final + (y - p8y);
        }
    // Now checks which is the highest
    // 1
    if(p1final > p2final && p1final > p3final && p1final > p4final && p1final > p5final && p1final > p6final && p1final > p7final && p1final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P1Final");
        if(x > p1x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p1x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p1y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p1y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 2
    if(p2final > p1final && p2final > p3final && p2final > p4final && p2final > p5final && p2final > p6final && p2final > p7final && p2final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P2Final");
        if(x > p2x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p2x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p2y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p2y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 3
    if(p3final > p1final && p3final > p2final && p3final > p4final && p3final > p5final && p3final > p6final && p3final > p7final && p3final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P3Final");
        if(x > p3x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p3x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p3y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p3y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 4
    if(p4final > p1final && p4final > p2final && p4final > p3final && p4final > p5final && p4final > p6final && p4final > p7final && p4final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P4Final");
        if(x > p4x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p4x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p4y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p4y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 5
    if(p5final > p1final && p5final > p2final && p5final > p3final && p5final > p4final && p5final > p6final && p5final > p7final && p5final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P5Final");
        if(x > p5x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p5x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p5y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p5y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 6
    if(p6final > p1final && p6final > p2final && p6final > p3final && p6final > p4final && p6final > p5final && p6final > p7final && p6final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P6Final");
        if(x > p6x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p6x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p6y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p6y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 7
    if(p7final > p1final && p7final > p2final && p7final > p3final && p7final > p4final && p7final > p5final && p7final > p6final && p7final > p8final){
        System.out.println("P7Final");
        if(x > p7x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p7x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p7y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p7y){
            y+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
    // 8
    if(p8final > p1final && p8final > p2final && p8final > p3final && p8final > p4final && p8final > p5final && p8final > p6final && p8final > p7final){
        System.out.println("P8Final");
        if(x > p8x){
            x-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(x < p8x){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y > p8y){
            y-=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
        if(y < p8y){
            x+=7;
            Game.dogrepaint = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Since that is basically gibberish and just a long line of if statements, and it still isn't working, I'm trying to find a much simpler or actual working way of doing this.

TLDR: The dog won't follow the player at a range of 100 pixels at all times.

Comment: you should restructure your objects. pass a `Dog` object which contains all the state of the dog and a `Player` object which contains all the state of the player. then, have a function which calculates distance between the two (in OOP tradition, probably a superclass of the `Dog` and `Player`, being some kind of `GameObject` class that has a `GameObject.distanceTo(GameObject)` method) and then do your logic from there

Comment: secondarily, i don't see why people are downvoting this. clearly, the asker has attempted an effort. it's a huge effort that has become, even to their knowledge, a mess. we ought not penalise people simply for daring to ask people on the internet for assistance

Comment: 300ish lines of code is not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I agree with ifly here on restructuring. Also, it's very good practice while coding to have more descriptive comments especially when you have others viewing your code. A lot of the code looks similar, which actually makes it really hard to debug (imo). If you ever find yourself doing something repetitive, think how a function/class structure might be able to simplify this with just passing arguments.